# Type a backtick in a single press

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I use backticks in programming on mostly OS X but sometimes Windows.

Can I configure the system so that I can type them in a single press?
I don't care for those òìè just these <kbd>`</kbd>

Comment: It may depend on your keyboard language layout - on UK keyboards, Mac it's to the left of z, no modifier needed, Windows is left of 1, again no modifier.

Comment: Windows > You may have to change the keyboard layout to the appropriate non-international version if currently you need to press "``" to get a single "`"